# send file using WebSocket in Android

Tags: android, autobahn

I want to send image or text file using `WebSocket` in `android` as of now i am using [AutoBahnAndroid](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid) to create a pubsub model , but i need a feature to send files.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a "send file" functionality on top of the raw WebSocket API - which supports (non-encoded) binary payloads). AutobahnAndroid itself does not offer a "send file" API.

Comment: do you have some reference related to tht or a road map ?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but we have no plans to build "sendfile" into AutobahnAndroid.